# XY model free energy temperature limits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature, approximations

The free energy of the XY model for $ N \rightarrow \infty $ given by:

$$
F = -\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{\beta N} \ln Z = -\dfrac{1}{\beta}\ln[2\pi I_0(\beta J)]
$$

where $I_n(z) = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{d\phi}{2\pi} e^{z\cos \phi}\cos n\phi$.

How do we compute the high and low temperature limits of F?

Answer (score 0):

Here you could use [the asymptotic forms of the Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms), and consider limits $\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}\rightarrow 0$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}\rightarrow +\infty$.

I suggest that you get hold of copies (or pdfs) of [Abramovitz&Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun) and [Gradshtein&Ryzhik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradshteyn_and_Ryzhik) - indespensable for working with special functions.